# C# The type of initializer for crystaldecisions.crystalreports.engine.reportdocument' threw an exception

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, runtime-error

I'm working on c# windows application .net framework 4.5.2 32 bit, windows 8.

I user Crystal report in my project CRforVS_13_0_15  this i use in my project but when i try to deploy my project in client pc i get an error message

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click
>   Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to
>   continue. If you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> The type initializer for
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument threw an
>   exception

[image]

Comment: What does the innerException say, and maybe try setting your .Net version to 4.5

Comment: This is the essential part: "...Could not load file or assembly log4net, Version=1.2.10.0....". Did you deploy that file?